# Parametric functions to describe the intersection of two orthogonal cylinder surfaces?

Tags: integration, inverse-function

I am trying to find a parametric equation for the intersection line of the surface of two orthogonal cylinders, $\vec{P}$ is a point that belongs to this intersection:

$$\vec{P(t)} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} r_1 cos \alpha(t) \\ - \\ r_1 sin \alpha(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} - \\ r_2 cos \beta(t) \\ z_0 - r_2 sin \beta(t)\end{bmatrix}$$

I tried to solve this by adding the following constraint:

$$\lVert\frac{d}{dt}\vec{P(t)}\rVert = 1$$

It does not matter where we start and which direction we start, so to pick one, one could say:

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&\alpha(0) = 0\\
&\beta(0) \ge 0\\
&\frac{d\alpha}{dt}\big|_{t=0} \gt 0
\end{align*}\right.$$

But I arrive at - to me - seemingly unsolvable equations, see below.

$$r_1^2\left(\frac{d\alpha}{dt}\right)^2+r_2^2sin^2\beta\left(\frac{d\beta}{dt}\right)^2 = 1$$

$$r_2\left(\frac{cos^2\beta}{\left(1-\left(z_0^2-2 z_0 r_2 sin\beta + r_2^2 cos^2\beta\right)\right)} + sin^2\beta\right) d\beta = dt$$

(I must have made a mistake as there is no $r_1$ in the last equation, but I think this is pretty close to what needs solving).

So first I'd have to find solve this integral, then I'd have to inverse the function - I do not think that either of those is going to happen.

Did I do anything wrong, or is there a simpler way to go about it?

Comment: Nope, the Steinmetz solid is the intersection of cylinders of equal radii with no offset - I have both an offset and different radii.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I should have read the question carefully.

Comment: That's Ok ;-), thanks for trying